# Howto connect bluetooth keyboard to non bluetooth pc?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, keyboard, bluetooth-3.0

I have a bluetooth keyboard that didn't come with a reciever. I want to connect it to my desktop pc, which doesn't have a bluetooth adapter.

Is there any way I can do it like by connecting it with bluetooth to my phone and then connect my phone and PC to the same Wifi, or something like that?

Comment: You need a USB bluetooth adapter:   https://www.amazon.ca/Plugable-Bluetooth-Adapter-Raspberry-Compatible/dp/B009ZIILLI

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB Adapter for this application. Set up the USB adapter and then let it detect the Bluetooth Keyboard. I am quite sure you cannot use your phone to hook up the keyboard.

Here is a list of possible adapters for computers.

[USB Bluetooth Adapters](https://gadgets-reviews.com/ca/review/2043-best-bluetooth-adapters-for-pcs.html)

> What is a Bluetooth Adapter? Sometimes also called a “dongle,” a
> Bluetooth adapter is any device designed to connect to a PC, laptop,
> or mobile device and provide a Bluetooth connection service. Bluetooth
> adapters are often small USB plug-and-play devices with nothing more
> than an antenna for transmitting and receiving data and a few
> Bluetooth chips. Others are larger devices that sit on a desktop to
> provide connections to devices that aren’t wireless or give a boost to
> a connection’s range.
>
> **Consider this Adapter (there are many and this is an example. Also consider an Adapter from the manufacturer of the Keyboard.**
>
> Avantree DG40S USB Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter - Multi-Use Adapter
>
> The DG40S is a multi-purpose Bluetooth adapter from Avantree that can
> be used with PCs, laptops, tablets, and smartphones.
>
> It’s only compatible with Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10, and it’s designed
> to upgrade computers without a built-in Bluetooth capability.

Comment: I am fairly sure you cannot use your phone to adapt the keyboard, so you do need the correct adapter. They are not expensive.